# How do you make the gradle SSH plugin use SCP instead of SFTP?

Tags: gradle, ssh, scp

I'm using the gradle SSH plugin to copy a docker file to a target host.  It defaults to SFTP but I'd prefer to use SCP.  [The documentation](https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/docs/) does not provide a clear example of how to do this and it's late and I'm tired and...

So anyway, here's what is working for me with SFTP:

```
ssh.run {
  session(remotes.my_host) {
    put from:"${dockerImageArchive}", into:"/tmp"
  }
}
```

Here's what the docs say I need to do to switch to SCP:
[image: gradle ssh documentation snippet]

I'm pretty new to gradle and I don't understand how I'm supposed to supply this parameter.  Can someone spell it out for me? :)

FWIW I've tried this

```
ssh.run {
  session(remotes.my_host) {
    put from:"${dockerImageArchive}", into:"/tmp", fileTransfer:"scp"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, turns out this was waaay easier than I expected.  I needed to add this to my build.gradle (could have also been added somewhere else in the inheritance hierarchy)

```
ssh.settings {
  fileTransfer = 'scp'
}
```